# Making 'this' equal the caller in Javascript function assignment

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm trying to ensure I have a valid *this* reference in the caller.receiver method below.

This is a simplified example but I have some function assignments such as:

```
service.fn = this.receiver
```

However, when the receiver function executes I want *this* to reference caller, i.e. I want the string 'Caller - Received' to be output to the console log.

```
var service = {
    name: 'Service',
    fn: null,
    runFn: function () {
        this.fn(arguments);
    }
};

var caller = {
    name: 'Caller',
    receiver: function () {
        console.log(this.name + ' - Received');
    },
    perform: function () {
        service.fn = this.receiver;
        service.runFn();
    }
};

caller.perform();
```

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Use `.apply()` to set the value of `this` in your functions.

Comment: If you look over your code there, you are setting the service.fn to point to the function() { console.log(this.name + ' - Received'); }  In the context of service and this function, 'this' is a reference to service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method to the object:

```
perform: function () {
    service.fn = this.receiver.bind(this);
    service.runFn();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can trust that bind native function will be in all browsers

Comment: @Adidi sigh. It's does not require any native functionality, it can be user implemented. Any framework also provides a function to bind that works in all browsers...

Comment: This looks good and best for my needs, although I've seen this problem solved without using bind(). I don't really have the time to investigate though! Thanks @Esailija

Comment: @Esailija not true man - IE8 does not support bind native - and of course every framework supports it - but this is a question on a pure js so...

Comment: @Adidi What I mean that bind doesn't need any magic tricks and can be implemented in user code. Contrast to for example getters and setters which truly require support from the browser and cannot be done using user code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Recieve reference to the function and then use apply: 
http://jsfiddle.net/d5tf2/

```
        var service = {
        name: 'Service',
        fn: null,
        runFn: function (ref) {
            this.fn.apply(ref,arguments);
        }
    };

    var caller = {
        name: 'Caller',
        receiver: function () {
            console.log(this.name + ' - Received');
        },
        perform: function () {
            service.fn = this.receiver;
            service.runFn(this);
        }
    };

    caller.perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Adidi, as I said to Dan I won't have a reference to the caller when the function executes - it is essentially called from within the service, but the caller's receiver function still needs access to other properties inside the caller object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var service = {
    name: 'Service',
    fn: null,
    runFn: function () {
        this.fn(arguments);
    }
};

var getCaller = function(){
    var that;
    return {
        name='Caller',
        receiver: function () {
            console.log(that.name + ' - Received');
        },
        perform: function () {
            that = this;
            service.fn = this.receiver;
            service.runFn();
        }
    }
};
var caller = getCaller();
caller.perform();
```

Interesting read: http://jason.pettys.name/2011/10/06/javascript-this-and-that/

Answer (score -1):

Pass this in

```
var service = {
    name: 'Service',
    fn: null,
    runFn: function (arguments) {
        this.fn(arguments);
    }
};

var caller = {
    name: 'Caller',
    receiver: function (that) {
        console.log(that.name + ' - Received');
    },
    perform: function () {
        service.fn = this.receiver;
        service.runFn(this);
    }
};

caller.perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I won't have a reference to the caller when the fn function actually is called. I probably should have made that clear.